# How do I get rid of the repeats within the filtered array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to get an array of the week but instead have their months rather than the date or day so one week including today would be `["Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar"]`, but I only want the array to show when there is a change so instead I want it to be like `["Feb","", "Mar", "", "", "", ""]`

```
var month = [String]()//this includes the months for the whole week
var filterdmonth = ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
for(var s = 0; s < month.count; s++){
    if(month[s] != filterdmonth[0]){
        filterdmonth[s] = month[s]
        print(filterdmonth)
    }

}
```

This prints out `["Feb", "", "Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar",]`

Comment: should put them into a `Set`, that way there will be no duplicates

Comment: How do I do that. I am not aware of how to use sets

Comment: depends how important it is to keep blank spaces in your array like that, but a set is just another type of array, but does not allow duplicate entries of elements. `var filteredMonth = Set<String>()` but you wont be able to include multiple blanks like how you have it initially setup

Comment: I need the multiple blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your input is, but if `month` is `["Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar"]`, then here is something simple I got working.

```
let months = ["Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar"]
var workingMonth = ""

let filteredMonths = months.map { month -> String in
    let result = month != workingMonth ? month : ""

    if month != workingMonth {
        workingMonth = month // There is a new month, so update the working month.
    }

    return result
}

print(filteredMonths)
```